# How to connect USB Wireless headset via USB (Skullcandy)

Tags: usb, sound, bluetooth

I have this bluetooth USB headset and I don't have an adapter to be able to connect my headset to it. So I wanted to be able to connect the headset through the USB directly and it doesn't appear to detect the device.

Comment: Get a bluetooth dongle. No, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the whole Skullcandy range of [wireless headphones](http://In%20the%20whole%20Skullcandy%20range%20of%20wireless%20headphones%20the%20USB%20connection%20is%20for%20charging%20only.) the USB connection is for charging only.

Comment: Well that sucks. I didn't even want the headphones but I got them as a Christmas gift. Yay gifts that I have to pay money to use.